# JavaFX Bounds and CSS

Tags: javafx-2

I have a node in JavaFx-application that has an ImageView, which has the size `200,200`.

In CSS-file for that node I define an inset for background and border:

```
.my-item { 
    -fx-background-insets: -15;
    -fx-border-color: #ccc;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-insets: -15;
}
```

This leads to an ImageView with a border that has `15px` of space. Alright. Later in code I want to get the bounds for this item *including this 15px* for the border.

But the methods `getBoundsInParent().getWidth()` or `getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()` return `200px`. So how can I get the size that I see on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

ImageView doesn't have an `-fx-border-insets` and `-fx-background-insets` properties. Thats why its width doesn't change. If you try the same with button method `getBoundsInParent().getWidth()` will return width with borders.